# I can't get the results I'm looking for with regex and nested items

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on some regex right now to isolate bracketed code such as this...

```
Regex: /\[(.*?)\]/

String: "<strong>[name]</strong>
<a href="http://www.example.com/place/[id]/">For more info...</a>"

Matched Fields: name, id
```

I'm looking to make this a bit more advanced. What I'm looking to do...

```
String: "[if:name <strong>[name]</strong>]
<a href="http://www.example.com/place/[id]/">For more info...</a>"

Matched Fields: if:name <strong>[name]</strong>, id
```

The problem is, I can't figure out any regex that'll work for this. I'm pretty sure I've killed the better half of my day, and I feel like I'm pretty close.

Here's what I've got at the moment that isn't doing what I want...

```
/\[([^\]]+)\]/
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Nesting is usually bad for regex, but in some languages it's possible. That said, what language are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty confused... about what you want to do.

Comment: Please Provide some examples with different data, and WHAT you are expecting to match. Looks not very difficult, but your "IF[...]" is confuing - is that part of the string, or is it a condition to match?

Comment: I'm using PHP. I'd like to be able to pull "[this statement, even when I do things like [this] and [that] in my statement]"

Comment: The IF condition is something I'd handle on the programming. I'm looking to recognize some conditional statements in my replacements and process those. For the context of the questions I could have written [FLAMINGO:GIRAFFE some content [ZIBRA] some more content], I'd still want to return everything in the outter most brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP supports recursive syntax (like `(?R)`), so you can use this regex:

```
\[((?:[^\[\]]+|(?R))+)\]
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/kM0hX8)

The results are: `if:name <strong>[name]</strong>`, `id`

`(?R)` is a repeat of the whole regex, hence 'recursive'. The other characters should be easy enough to understand, if not, regex101 provides quite a comprehensive description of the components of the regex :)

Comment: don't think this is the solution, but +1 for pointing out the `(?R)` pretty cool :)

Comment: This gets me pretty close. My next challenge will be isolating the IF: in [IF:something blah [recursive]] portion as opposed to [onefield], but you answered exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @dognose I'm pretty sure this is what OP is looking for :)

Comment: @Jerry Dude, we always battle for Regex answers have you noticed that? Sadly, you generally win.

Comment: @progenhard Oh hi! I guess... But I don't see it as being winning or losing, it's more about helping the OP. I won't be around for a good while now, my eyelids are dropping xD Good luck on the incoming questions :)

Comment: I appreciate all the help for sure. I can usually get anywhere I need with regex, but I have never seen ?R before and wasn't familiar with it. you guys have all definitely saved me a TON of time trying to figure this one out!!

Comment: @JohnSly You're welcome :) Recursion wasn't my strong suit either, but after some practice, I understand it a little more to be able to do some simple recursions like in your question :D

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a Regex for html etc its easier to parse the file.  Not sure what language your using so I will give an example of parser in Java.  [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) allows you to access the document using CSS selectors.  Makes things so much easier!  Take a look through the tutorials etc and see if that makes it easier.

Regex are nice and powerful dont get me wrong but give a parser a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[(.*)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/JEJbH36kDbMkF9FW)

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you just want balanced brackets and/or recurse core's for inner brackets. Many nested levels could be done. This is just a framwork for a possible much more complex usage. The balanced text part is actually easier.

```
 # (?:(?>[^\\\[\]]+|(?:\\[\S\s])+)|(?>\[((?:(?&core)|))\]())|([\[\]])())(?:\2|\4)(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>[^\\\[\]]++|(?:\\[\S\s])++|\[(?:(?&core)|)\])+))

 (?:
      (?>
           [^\\\[\]]+ 
        |  
           (?: \\ [\S\s] )+
      )
   |  
      (?>
           \[
           (                       # (1) core content
                (?:
                     (?&core) 
                  |  
                )
           )
           \]
           ( )                     # (2) core flag
      )
   |  
      # unbalanced '[' or ']'
      ( [\[\]] )                   # (3) error content
      ( )                          # (4) error flag
 )

 (?: \2 | \4 )            # only let match if core flag or error flag is set
                          # this filters search to square brackets only
 (?(DEFINE)
      # core
      (?<core>
           (?>
                [^\\\[\]]++ 
             |  
                (?: \\ [\S\s] )++
             |  
                \[
                # recurse core
                (?:
                     (?&core) 
                  |  
                )
                \]
           )+
      )
 )


 # Perl sample, but regex should be valid in php
 # ----------------------------
 # use strict;
 # use warnings;
 # 
 # 
 # $/ = "";
 # 
 # my $data = <DATA> ;
 # 
 # parse( $data ) ;
 # 
 # 
 # sub parse
 # {
 #      my( $str ) = @_;
 #      while 
 #      (
 #           $ str =~ /
 #               (?:(?>[^\\\[\]]+|(?:\\[\S\s])+)|(?>\[((?:(?&core)|))\]())|([\[\]])())(?:\2|\4)(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>[^\\\[\]]++|(?:\\[\S\s])++|\[(?:(?&core)|)\])+))
 #           /xg 
 #      )
 #      
 #      {
 #           if ( defined $1 )
 #           {
 #                print "found core \[$1\] \n";
 #                parse( $1 ) ;
 #           }
 #           if ( defined $3 )
 #           {
 #                print "unbalanced error '$3' \n";
 #           }
 #           
 #      }     
 # }
 # __DATA__
 # 
 # this [ [ is a test
 # [ outter [ inner ] ]
```